# Creating a specific lookup array

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make a formula that looks up the cells

```
E9&E10
E9&F10
G9&G10
G9&H10
```

Currently, I have this formula

```
XLOOKUP($E$19&E$20,$E$9:$G$9&$E$10:$H$10,....)
```

I believe the issue is that this formula looks up F9&F10 and H9&H10 (this produces an error since I excluded H9).

I am stuck on how to proceed from here though. I just can't seem to figure out how to get E9&F10 instead of F9&F10 and G9&H10 instead of H9&H10.

Comment: What do you mean by "looks up cells"? What are you trying to do? If you show us your input and expected output, I'm sure somebody will be able to help.

Comment: `&` is for concatenation.  If `E9=436` and `E10=715` then  `E9&E10=436715`

Comment: Do you have a sample about your requirement?